# Assuming equal changes in terms of percentage points for two populations. Very easy question, but a reference needed

Tags: references

How to explain to non-statisticians that if we have e.g. obesity rate equal to 40% in men and 12% in women, the target values in men and women in 2030 should NOT be equal to 38% in men and 10% in women? Do you know any paper/guide that would explain it to policy-makers that one should take into account the baseline level, when assuming the target values? Actually, I would like to show that time series of social indicators are more likely to show exponential trends instead of linear trends. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the rates can't decrease? Second, what is a forcasted target? A forecast is a guess; a target is a wish.

Comment: I meant target values. Actually, I would like to show that it is unfair to demand decrease of obesity rate by 2 percentage points both in men and women, since the baseline levels equal to 40% and 12%, respectively. I would like to justify the need of assuming a relative reduction, as Stephan Kolassa stated.

Comment: That's a huge difference, and you should edit the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a difference between a *forecast* (what we *expect* to happen *given* specific circumstances) and a *target* (what we *want* to happen, and are prepared to *change* circumstances to achieve).

Second, to your question: I believe that this point is so trivial that nobody would publish anything on it. And it should be easily explainable. I doubt that someone who will not or cannot follow the explanation would be convinced by a reference.

You may have more luck in *framing* the development differently. "Obesity incidence will be reduced by 10% in both men and women" is a *relative* reduction and translates into a reduction from 40% to 36% in men and from 12% to 10.8% in women.